# class "org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.MailboxExecutor" not found

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, apache-hudi

when I use hudi 0.10.1 and flink1.14.0  , I got an exception
" not found class  org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.MailboxExecutor"

I found "MailboxExecutor" is in the flink1.13.1 , how can I do it？

complie with flink 1.14 ?

Comment: I complied with flink1.14.0 ,got exception !

Answer (score 1):

https://hudi.apache.org/docs/next/flink-quick-start-guide

Hudi works with **Flink-1.13.x** version. You can follow instructions here for setting up Flink. The hudi-flink-bundle jar is archived with scala 2.11, so it’s recommended to use flink 1.13.x bundled with scala 2.11.